# Creating Bar plot of dp[Column] that contains string 'Exact string'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to create a bar chart of the count of rows in a column that contain the string `'Exactstring'`.

```py
data['Genre'].value_counts().plot.bar(color='#1B9E77')
```

Here I want the `value_count` of the rows in `data['Genre']` that contain the string `'Action'`.

Comment: Can you provide more details ?

Comment: It would help if you could show us a sample of the input dataframe. See [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)